# One side half twist mobius band are one to one transformation on extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to understand how one side half twist mobius are one to one transformation on extended complex plane $C^{*} = \mathbb{C} \cup \infty$

I don't ask for full proof, but I do want "something" geometric intuitive,
e.g. stereographic projection from sphere to complex extended plane

Comment: Mobius transformations and Mobius bands are unrelated, other than that they were both studied by Mobius.

Comment: There is conformal map from sphere to complex extended plane, and there is map from one side half twist mobius band to complex extended plane. I think there is natural question: what is the map or is there any map  from one side half twist band to sphere

Comment: What map from the Mobius band to the Riemann sphere are you talking about?

Comment: This is my question actually,

Comment: I have never come across such a one-one transformation.  Where did you hear that there was one?

Comment: Page 3, on mobius transformation. http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/ModularGroup/ModularGroup.pdf

Comment: The link you refer to literally says "...named after the same mathematician with whom...". It does not say that Mobius bands are Mobius transformations. These are, again, unrelated concepts.